# How to insert Text(Header, Paragraphs) inside of an Image in Semantic-UI-React

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, semantic-ui-react

this is an issue that has been troubling me for quite some time now, and I can't seem to find a solution. I am trying to add text inside of an Image, but it won't work.

This is my code so far:

```
 <Grid.Column width={4}>
                    <Image
                        src={img2}
                        label={{ as: 'a', color: 'red', content: 'HOT', 
                                icon: 'fire', ribbon: true }}
                        as='a'
                        size='massive'
                        href='http://google.com'
                        target='_blank'
                    />
                    <Header> This is the header </Header>
                    <p> This is info about the header </p>
</Grid.Column>
```

Now I've tried adding content, or putting the Header and p inside of the Image, but to no luck. Shouldn't this be part of the code that Semantic should provide us with?

Comment: you can just use CSS for positioning the text above the image.

Comment: could you provide me with an example please, as I am still a little new to all this and learning :)

Comment: It would depend on the react styling techniques you are following. But try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)